# Combine sales data without knowing the number of sold units per one sale

Tags: mysql, database-design

I’d like to consult for a strategy plan of a database structure for the following scenario:

My app is for offices buildings sales reports where a building is the basic unit that I need to generate the reports for. The reports for a sale of a single office are straightforward, I have the `building`, `offices` and `sales` tables and just take it from there.

However, a sale is not limited to one office – one buyer, but one buyer can purchase several offices and combine them to one big office.

Now, since the original data is based on the original basic office unit (*id, building_id, address, type, floor, space, number_of_rooms, description, sales_person_id,* etc.) I need to find a way to combine few units (offices) as one sale.

The data for actual sale of combined offices is fed by the sales person as one sale and there’s no split of the sale data, they just mark the offices in this sale as combined.

My first thought was to split the sales data like so:

- Tables `buildings` and `units` (and all the rest like sales persons, units types, etc.).
- The `sales` table, as the name suggests, holds sale-specific details.
- The `combined_units_in_sale` table will keep the IDs of each sale, one row per basic unit with the sale ID from `sales`.

I feel this is not how it should be and need some sanity check.

Here is the diagram I created so far (please ignore the data types shown in it):

[image]

Comment: Do you have an idea where else can I consult about this issue?